# About the reference of an element in container

Tags: c++, reference, containers

Can anyone tell me is it safe for a function to return the reference (i.e. `Type&`) of an element in a container (e.g. `boost::unordered_map`)?

If we can do so, why? Because I think the reference type works in the same way as pointers (correct me if I'm wrong), and the memory address of an element in the container may change over time, so what if referenced is no longer what it was before. Am I right?

If we can, can we return the pointer of an element in the container?

I have this question because I saw this occurs in others' code, and it works just fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

It's perfectly fine, so long as the container is never modified.  If the container **is** modified, then each container class has its own rules about when references to existing elements become invalidated.

The C++ standard is the official way to find the rules, but for the most part, you'll be safe reading a good online reference (no pun intended), such as http://cppreference.com.  For example, we learn that [`std::vector::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) will definitely invalidate references to all subsequent elements, and may invalidate references to all elements.

Comment: Then how can I know whether a reference is invalidated. Will it throw a run-time error when accessing that reference?

Comment: @user2100910: There is no programmatic way to know.  If you access something through an invalid reference, you may or may not see a runtime error (it's undefined behaviour).